# Unable to set form action via javascript (error:object doesn't support this property or method)

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer, action

Here is the code. `patient` is the form name.

```
function settarget(page) {
    document.getElementById('patient').action = page;
}
```

The exact error message from IE is:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

I have also tried it referencing `document.forms[0].action` - same error.

There is no duplication of the name `patient` for any other tag.

This works with Chrome and Firefox, but not IE8 on XP or IE9 on Win7.  Is there a security setting in IE that is blocking this action?

Comment: _"'patient' is the form name"_ - I assume you mean "the form id", given that you're using `getElementById()`? Please show your html, and perhaps how you call the `settarget()` function.

Answer (score 7):

DOM elements (returned by getElementById) [do not have a property `action`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element). You need to [set an attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute) on the element.

```
document.getElementById('patient').setAttribute('action',page)
```