# javascript form field submit : Object doesn't support this property or method in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

i'm getting following error in IE8

```
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

i'm getting this error on following line

```
fieldName.form.action = 'some action url';
```

i have alerted fieldName like following

```
alert(typeof(fieldName));
```

it alerts 'Object'

anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: html input file field i.e. `<input type='file' name='fieldName' id='fieldName' >`

Comment: can you show your html and scripts

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById("fieldName").form.action = ...`?

Comment: And is the element actually inside a form? Perhaps you could edit your question to show an extract of your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved the problem by replacing following line

```
fieldName.form.action = 'some action url';
```

to

```
fieldName.form.setAttribute('action','some url');
```

got answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825806/unable-to-set-form-action-via-javascript-errorobject-doesnt-support-this-prop?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
document.form_name.action='some url';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('IdOfForm').action='some action URL';
```